# Can't select CA certificate

Tags: android-11, certificates

Even after installing a CA certificate, I am not able to select it in the network configuration. I just get this message "CA certificate must be selected" but I can't find where I can do it.

[image]

How can I select the certificate I have just installed?

Comment: Have you tried to touch the `Select certificate` link shown in your screen shot?

Comment: Yes, it opens the drop down menu to choose "Select certificate", "Use system certificates" or "Don't Validate". Then I click "Select certificate" again, and I get the same thing in the photo again

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, how do you select the certificate when there is no dropdown or input field?

Well, this is insanely counterintuitive (at least for me), in order to pick the correct certificate for WiFi, you need to install it first. Assuming you have your cert file, you need to copy it to the 'Internal memory' folder on your phone. It is very important, otherwise, you will not see the certificate later on.

Now go to Settings -> "Security" -> "Encryption & credentials" -> "Install a certificate" -> "Wi-Fi certificate" and select your certificate. Enter name and install it. Now it will be available from the dropdown in WiFi connection menu.